# How to set month value based on count

Tags: javascript

How to get the correct month in javascript. I don't want to use any plugin for this.

```js
var date = new Date();
var month = date.getMonth();
// value is 06 current month;

var month = date.getMonth() + 15;
// now value is 21
```

Here, if the getMonth() count more than 12 means how can I get the correct month.
If more than 12 means I need to increase the year also right.

For Example,

```js
// assume current month December
var month = date.getMonth()+3;  // value is 14
```

I want to show the month as "03" (MARCH). Please help me how can I do this

Comment: actually, `new Date().getMonth()` is 5, not 6.

Comment: use `setMonth(date.getMonth()+3)`, setMonth is supposed to be range proof.

Answer (score 2):

Do with `%12` .it will subtract the month with 12 .Remaining will show on

***Note:*** Remember  month value start from 0 `0=January`

```js
var date = new Date();
var month = date.getMonth();
console.log('default month value ='+month)
month = (date.getMonth() + 15) % 12;
console.log(month)
```

Comment: this is wrong. June + 15 months should be September, not August.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var date = new Date();
var month = date.getMonth();

var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];

var month = date.getMonth() + 15;

var result = new Date(date.getYear(),month,date.getDay()).getMonth();

console.log(result, monthNames[result]);
```

Comment: this is wrong. June + 15 months should be September, not August.

Comment: month is zero based. So monthNames[result] would work

Answer (score 0):

You may set the month, causing it to also change the year:

```
var date=new Date();
alert(date+"");
date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 15);
alert(date+"");
```

The js engine already takes care of month overflows...

Answer (score 0):

Seems like everybody's answer is incorrect.

`date.getMonth()` returns an integer equivalent of the month, zero-based, so `new Date().getMonth()` returns 5, not 6. Thus, `month + 15` = 20, not 21.

from June, we add 15 months:

```
1. July
2. August
3. Sept
4. Oct
5. Nov
6. Dec
7. Jan
8 Feb
9 Mar
10 Apr
11 May
12 June
13 July
14 Aug
15 Sept
```

So, it's September, not August!!!

```js
var date = new Date(),
  monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
  ];
var month = date.getMonth(); //current month is 5, 0 based. january = 0, feb = 2, .... dec = 11
//console.log(month);
month = date.getMonth() + 15; //value becomes 20, not 21
//console.log(month);

var newDT = new Date(date.getFullYear(), month, date.getDate());
console.log("today's date is:" + date.getDate());

var newMonth = newDT.getMonth();
console.log("Current month plus 15 months is " + (newMonth + 1));
console.log("Month name is " + monthNames[newMonth]); //don't need to add 1 since our monthNames is zero-based
```